# Can I save pastor William?

Tags: state-of-decay

Shortly after completing the mission Home Away From Home, pastor William contracts black fever and, after a few days, gets shot by Alan. Is there any reliable way to save William and retain his stamina-restoring radio command? I had heard that moving to the trucking yard safehouse immediately after completing Home Away From Home can save him, but this hasn't been the case in my current game.

Comment: I've never managed to save him and I tried many different ideas. I've never heard of anyone successfully doing it either.

Comment: Sheesh spoiler alert in title!

Comment: @Evorlor gasp, a character in a zombie game can end up in a perilous situation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is an element of the game's plot.